# Math.sin incorrect results even when converted to degrees

Tags: javascript, math, degrees, radians

I'm trying to use sin on a variable and I saw you can convert it by using / (Math.PI / 180) but that seems contradictory if you want to convert it to degrees.. How do I properly convert and use sin in degree form? (On an iPhone calculator, for example it returns ~.707 from an input of 45, while this returns ~.806).

```
function click25() {
    if (vi === 0) {
        reactant = Math.sin(reactant / (Math.PI / 180))
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to *multiply* the angle in degrees by `Math.PI / 180`, not divide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to multiply the value in degree by `(pi/180)` to convert into the equivalent value in radians

```js
var reactant = 45;
var vi = 0;
function click25() {
    if (vi === 0) {
        reactant = Math.sin(reactant * (Math.PI / 180))
    }
    console.log(reactant);
}

click25();
```

Comment: What about for asin, in my phone calc it returns 53 for .8 while                                                    reactant = Math.asin(reactant * (Math.PI / 180)); returns .01396

Comment: @Benn you don't pass an angle to Asin or any of the other inverse trig functions, because they *return* an angle.

Comment: so what is the proper usage in degrees for asin acos and atan